# Spreadsheet Function Syntax Correction

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

Here's what I'm trying to do:
My spreadsheet has 3 sheets, I'm making a new one to summarize the data.
The sheet I'm currently trying to summarize from is called "flavors" and
it's data on the amount sold of a specific flavor in a certain week.
The columns are "week:sold:flavors".
Now on my new sheet I'm trying to count the sold amount of a certain flavor.

Here's the function I am trying to use; =COUNTIF(flavors!B2:B209,C2:C209="chocolate")

I thought it was countif, then 'flavors'! is the reference page, B2:B209 is the range of
the specific column. Then the criteria is in the range of C2:C209 = the flavor chocolate.
However the result I am getting is 0. I don't understand why however, what is the correct
syntax or what am I missing?

Here's a picture of the flavors sheet.
[Here's a picture of the flavors sheet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4izp.png)

Comment: If I understand correctly you need `=SUMIF(flavors!C$2:C$209,"chocolate",flavors!B$2:B$209)`

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=SUMIF(flavors!C2:C209; "chocolate"; flavors!B2:B209)
```